# Remove Category Base from WordPress Category URL

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks, radix

I fished around the internet for a solution to this, tried a plugin or two to remove the /category/ from wordpress url's.

While some of these plugins are good, the category **link** still display's /category/.

Also I've tried putting in ./ in the category base options in permalinks settings.

Does anyone know how I could do like a php search and replace or something like that?

Comment: Looks promising -- http://pitumbo.com/remove-category-and-or-tag-url-wordpress-3

Comment: Nah not what I'm looking for. I resorted to editing the rewrite.php core file. Problem solved.

Comment: "Problem solved." Actually, problem made more complex by altering WP core.

Comment: I am using a [WordPress plugin to remove category base](http://www.wordpressians.com/remove-category-slug-base-wordpress-urls/) from our WordPress blog. Hope this may help you the most.
Best Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/ and it doesn't alter permalinks, so removing it reverts the structure with no problem. And you don't have to alter core files.

Comment: Yes I already tried that plugin. It didn't do what I wanted it to as it still displayed the links in the HTML with /category at the base, although it re-directs to the page without the /category.

Comment: As I found this post and the plugin mentioned is now outdated, here is a new plugin currently being used and maintained, that should do the job: https://wordpress.org/plugins/no-category-base-wpml/

Answer (score 3):

A cleaner solution:

```
add_filter('user_trailingslashit', 'remcat_function');
function remcat_function($link) {
    return str_replace("/category/", "/", $link);
}
add_action('init', 'remcat_flush_rules');
function remcat_flush_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'remcat_rewrite');
function remcat_rewrite($wp_rewrite) {
    $new_rules = array('(.+)/page/(.+)/?' => 'index.php?category_name='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&paged='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(2));
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

Comment: Cleaner than what, a plugin, or the one-line solution above for functions.php file?

Answer (score 3):

Using WordPress 3.9.1 (latest version as of this post) I simply added a single line to my theme's `functions.php`...

```
$wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('category_base', '%category%');
```

Then I opened *Settings > Permalinks* and hit *Save*.  This appears to flush the permalink cache and makes it work.

Comment: i tried this option, but when i try to go to a subcategory page, it is confusing wordpress and it's taking me to a post with a similar slug to my category.

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/no-category-base-wpml/ is a plugin that solves the problem and works with current versions of WordPress.